# Hyperbolic coordinates

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

You can uniquely specify any point in 2D Euclidian space using 2 numbers: the distance from the infinitely long X-axis, and the distance from the infinitely long Y-axis.

How do you uniquely specify a point in 2D hyperbolic space? Can you do it with just 2 numbers? Can you do it in a "uniform" way? How would that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know the upper half space or disc model of hyperbolic space? In these, you can of course specify a point with 2 coordinates.

Comment: OK. But then how would you add or subtract coordinates? Clearly the usual Euclidian rules won't work...

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid: How would you add and subtract points in the hyperbolic plane to begin with? It's not a vector space.

Comment: You did not ask about adding coordinates in your OP. If you need an analogy to the distance description, then this can be achieved -- eg in the disc model -- using the inteersection of the disc with the Euclidean $x$ and $y$ axis and then use geodesic distance. ($x$ and $y$ axis are geodesics in that model).

Comment: (Oh and if you think of adding coordinates as translations -- the group of isometries of hyperbolic space is well known and easy to describe).

Comment: Check out any introduction to hyperbolic geometry.  *Lectures on Hyperbolic Geometry* by Benedetti and Petronio, *Three Dimensional Geometry and Topology* by Thurston are two books that come to mind.

Comment: Caroline Series's notes on the subject are particularly good. http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masbb/Papers/MA448.pdf